# JPA, Hibernate: Persist through multiple levels

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to persist through multiple levels in JPA (or Hibernate)? I have a table "resource" where each resource can be a "child" of another resource. This can happen through multiple levels. I am using a join table to contain the relationship.

What I want to achieve is this.

```
resource                                        resource_relations
========                                        ==================
resource_type | resource_name                   parent   | child
------------------------------                  --------------------
type1         | P                               P        | C
type2         | C                               C        | G  
type3         | G
```

My persistence entities look like this.

**Resource**

```
private String name;
private ResourceType resourceType;

public Resource(resourceType, name){ ... }   

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<ResourceRelation> components = new HashSet<ResourceRelation>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<ResourceRelation> parents = new HashSet<ResourceRelation>();

public void addComponent(Resource r) { /*add "r" to "components"*/ }
```

**ResourceRelation**

```
@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Resource parent;

@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Resource child;
```

Now, I execute the following statements:

```
parent = new Resource(type1, P);
child = new Resource(type2, C);
grandChild = new Resource(type3, G);
child.addComponent(grandChild);
parent.addComponent(child);
persist(parent);
```

However, only P and C are getting persistent but not G. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Your mapping is wrong, you shouldn't explicitly handle the table containing the relations betweens the resources. Hibernate will do it for you! Only the Resource class is needed here :

```
private String name;
private ResourceType resourceType;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Resource> components = new HashSet<Resource>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Resource> parents = new HashSet<Resource>();
```

Comment: For me, "resources" and "relations between resources" are two separate things. By which I mean that a "relation between resources" can be specified anytime after the resources have been created. So, I guess I would need a separate entity for the relational table.

Comment: No the relations between resources will be automatically created/updated by Hibernate every time you add/remove elements from the components or parents list even after the resource creation. Note that you will surely need to modify your cascading type to ALL.